# How to filter a Power BI service dashboard using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I'm automating tasks in the Power BI service, and I've been able to create dashboards.

But now I need something else: `Filter` them, how can I do this?

```
df = (pd.read_excel(str('../00_config/users.xlsx'), sheet_name = 'users', converters={'user':str}))

with open('../03_ouput/users.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file_csv:
    write_csv = csv.writer(file_csv)
    write_csv.writerow(['user', 'link'])
file_csv.close()

i = 0

# Obtenemos tablero inicial.
get_dashboard = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

if get_dashboard.status_code == 200:
    for cell_value in tqdm(column_users):
        new_dashboard_data = {
            "name": "Usuario - " + cell_value
        }
    
        clone_dashboard = requests.post(workspace_link_for_clone, json=new_dashboard_data, headers=headers)
        result_clone_dashboard = clone_dashboard.json()
        
        dashboard_link = result_clone_dashboard['webUrl']

        with open('../03_ouput/users.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file_csv:
            write_csv = csv.writer(file_csv)
            write_csv.writerow([cell_value, dashboard_link])
        file_csv.close()

        i+=1
else:
    print(get_dashboard.status_code)
```

That's my current code, what I did is run a loop to create boards in bulk, but now I also need to filter those boards with a different value each.

I tried to use powerbiclient, and I wrote this code statement (After having done the authentication)

```
report_edit = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=auth, view_mode=models.EmbedMode.EDIT.value, permissions=models.Permissions.READWRITE.value)
```

But I get this error:

> module 'pyexpat.model' has no attribute 'EmbedMode'

Comment: are you importing the models from correct library? (`from powerbiclient import models`) if yes and you still face the error, you can directly provide numerical values in `view_model` argument, check this [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-jupyter/blob/main/DOCUMENTATION.md#__init__-report) for more information.

Comment: I use 'import powerbiclient' only, Isn't that enough?

Comment: I did what you told me (from powerbiclient import models), and that error seems to have fixed. Now what I get when I get the filters is this error: 'Power BI report is not embedded'

Comment: If you used `import powerbiclient` instead of `from powerbiclient import models`, the correct reference to `models.EmbedMode.EDIT.value` would be `powerbiclient.models.EmbedMode.EDIT.value` please go through this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: It appears that you have already raised a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310096/exception-power-bi-report-is-not-embedded) regarding your second issue. Please provide a detailed explanation there.

Comment: I'll add my comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you are importing the models from the correct library (`from powerbiclient import models`).

if you are still facing the error, you can try directly providing the numerical values (VIEW: 0, EDIT: 1, CREATE: 2) in the `view_model` argument.

**Reference:**

[powerbi-jupyter
/DOCUMENTATION](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-jupyter/blob/main/DOCUMENTATION.md#__init__-report)