# Exception: Power BI report is not embedded

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I'm using powerbiclient with Python, I need to filter a dashboard, but I get this error:

> Exception: Power BI report is not embedded

This is the code line where I get the error:
`filters = report.get_filters()`

This is the authentication I have done and I have also generated an access token:

```
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()

access_token = device_auth.get_access_token()
```

How can I embed the Power BI report?

Comment: The error says that the Power BI report is not embedded, so maybe you can solve the error by embedding the Power BI report. I presume your question is how you can solve the error. Or what else is your question?

Comment: Correct, I would like to know how I can embed it

Comment: You'll need to provide more info.  Power BI reports can be embedded only in Javascript/HTML applications.  You might generate the Embed Token in a back-end Python/Flask API, but that's not where the embedding happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to [powerbi-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-jupyter).

Refer to [report.py](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-jupyter/blob/main/powerbiclient/report.py#LL478C4-L478C4) where it is throwing the exception message.
Faced similar issue earlier, and it turns out to be that the report class is not called.

Once report class is called, it will set the report object with report details for the wrapper. Then when we call any of the methods, it will use the same report object.

Make sure you initialize the report class by calling the report.
*Keeping it simple, display the report in the output cell and it will resolve the issue*. You can also check if report embedded by `report._embedded`.
Refer [Load Report in output cell](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-jupyter/blob/main/demo/Embed%20Power%20BI%20report%20demo.ipynb?short_path=a6f48c3#LL186C6-L186C6) to load the report.

If the issue still persists in your case, reframe your question with more details and sample code you are implementing.

Comment: What does it mean that "not rendered in the output cell"?

Comment: Modified my response. just call `report` in notebook it will call the report class and also display report. It should resolve the issue ideally. LMK if it's resolved or not